# binary search with JFLAP turing machine

Tags: turing-machines, jflap

A binary number is placed on the tape of a Turing machine (the input alphabet is {0, 1, □}). The head of the machine is positioned over the first element of the input. I need to write a program for the machine to check if the number on the tape is equal to your number 5.
When the machine terminates, there should be just one binary digit on the tape.

This digit should be 1, if the input was 5, otherwise it should be 0. The head should be positioned over this digit. Either assume S (stop) as a machine action, or use accepting states.